# A question on something relating to analytic continuation of a $\Gamma()$-based function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

$$f(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1}, \space (-1<Re(s)<0 : fundamental \space strip)$$

There exsists $\gamma$ that $0<Re(s)\le \gamma$, such that $f(s) = O({|s|}^{-p}), (p>1)$

That is, How to evaluate the rightmost $\gamma$ that $|{\frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1}}||s|^p \le C$ ?

Comment: The problem is a bit weirdly stated as on one hand you have $f(s)$ defined in $-1 < \Re s <0$ and on the other you ask for $\gamma >0$ so unclear what you want; if you want $\gamma<0$ then any such between $-1$ and $0$ will do with $O=O_{\gamma}$; otherwise there is a problem near $\sigma=0$ where $f$ is unbounded (near the roots of $2^s-1=0$) so it is not of the required size

Comment: Thank you. Conrad. It's you again. In fact, this is the continuation of the previous question, as followed.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-e^{-x/2^k}) \space \Rightarrow \space \frac{\Gamma(s)}{2^s-1},\space(-1<\text{Re}(s)<0)$$ by Mellin Transform, and its asymptotics (as $\space x\to\infty$) by Converse mapping
$$ \log_{2}{x} + \frac{\gamma}{\log2} + \frac{1}{2}+P(x)+O(x^{-1})$$
where P() is a $\Gamma()$ based periodic function.

As for $O(x^{-1})$, by Converse mapping, there exists $\gamma$ "somewhere the right side of fundamental strip" such that $f(s) = O(|s|^{-p})$.

Comment: So, I am not sure but I guess $\gamma = 1$. Btw, isn't it analytic continuation to extend s's range by changing the original form of the function? like $\Gamma()$?

Comment: this makes more sense now, though again one has to word the question carefully as the result holds for $0< \delta \le  \Re s \le \gamma$; in other words you need the abscissa to be on a compact interval that doesn't contain zero as you need a fixed positive distance (however small) from zero

Comment: Sorry. I am not that rigorous, now that I am just a beginner in Complex Analysis. You are so kind of me. Thanks. So, Can you find the $\gamma$? to make $f(s) = O(|s|^{-p})$ by Converse mapping-wise?